How to hide ad container if ad doesn't fill?
I have the following ad html:
<div class="ad-container">
  <p>Ad slot #1</p>
  <div id="ad-slot-1" class="ad-slot"></div>
</div>

and I'm calling this to collapse the ad if it doesn't fill:
googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();

The problem is that it only collapses the ad (ad-slot-1) and not the parent container. How can I make it hide the container as well?
You can play around with the code here: https://jsbin.com/kefajicemu/edit?html,output

collapseEmptyDivs() sets the style display: none on the div.ad-slot within div.ad-container. As such you can add a rule to your CSS to hide the containers when the child .ad-slot element is "cleaned up":


div.ad-container:has(> div.ad-slot[style*='display: none']) {
  display: none;
}

/* Purely for visualization purposes */
div.ad-container {
  border: 1px black solid;
}
<div class="ad-container">
  <p>Ad slot #1 - should be displayed, because child element <code>div#ad-slot-1</code> doesn't have <code>display: none</code> applied to its styling.</p>
  <div id="ad-slot-1" class="ad-slot"></div>
</div>
<div class="ad-container">
  <p>Ad slot #2 - should not be displayed, since the child is already hidden using <code>display: none;</code></p>
  <div id="ad-slot-2" class="ad-slot" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>



While CSS is the "correct" (more performant & more easily maintainable) answer here, you could also use JavaScript to apply this styling when you invoke googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();:


// In practice, you'd call googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs(); here, then:
document.querySelectorAll("div.ad-container:has(> div.ad-slot[style*='display: none'])").forEach(element => element.style.display = 'none');
/* Purely for visualization purposes */
div.ad-container {
  border: 1px black solid;
}
<div class="ad-container">
  <p>Ad slot #1 - should be displayed, because child element <code>div#ad-slot-1</code> doesn't have <code>display: none</code> applied to its styling.</p>
  <div id="ad-slot-1" class="ad-slot"></div>
</div>
<div class="ad-container">
  <p>Ad slot #2 - should not be displayed, since the child is already hidden using <code>display: none;</code></p>
  <div id="ad-slot-2" class="ad-slot" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>




You can also listen for the onSlotRenderEnded event:
window.googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function (e) {
    if (e.isEmpty) {
       const elementId = e.getSlotElementId();
       // Use this ID to then select the HTML you would like to hide
    }
});

